# Python multiprocessing pool shared between modules

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-module

I am trying to parallelize the code for one of my projects by using multiprocessing.
In this project I have 3 modules: A, B and C, each one of them contains a class with the same name of the module. The class in module A instances objects from modules B and C and is then instantiated by a script in another file that runs a function in it.

Now, each of these classes (A, B and C) has a method that runs some array manipulation that I would have it run in parallel. My approach until now has been to instantiate a pool inside the method, let it run the code that it needs to run and then terminate the pool when is done. 
Issue is that these methods are called multiple times, so creating and destroying the pool every time makes the code become slower and slower with time.

Is there a way to have a global pool that is share among the modules so they call it when they need it, without having to create and destroy it everytime?

```py
# A.py
import B, C

class A(){
  def __init__(self):
    b = B()
    c = C()

  def method(self):
    pool = mp.Pool()
    results = [pool.apply_async(self.parfunc, args=(i, )) for i in array]
    output = [p.get() for p in results]

  def main(self):
    b.method()
    c.method()
    self.method()
```

```py
# B.py
class B(){
  def method(self):
    pool = mp.Pool()
    results = [pool.apply_async(self.parfunc, args=(i, )) for i in array]
    output = [p.get() for p in results]
}
```

```py
# C.py
class C(){
  def method(self):
    pool = mp.Pool()
    results = [pool.apply_async(self.parfunc, args=(i, )) for i in array]
    output = [p.get() for p in results]
}
```

```py
# script.py
import A
if __name__ = '__main__':
  a = A()
  a.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options:

1. Pass the pool between the classes as a variable. The cap on the number of processes / threads is going to limit the process switching that is probably affecting you.
2. Call the processing intensive methods in the main script using the pool instantiated there. The benefit is that your classes do not need to contain any multiprocessing code.

Comment: I have done option 1, but still no change, after a while the code becomes much much slower. If I run it without multiprocessing instead is way faster and and the speed is consistent. Is there some kind of garbage collecting that might make the pool go slower with time?

Comment: I also noticed that it starts with all the cores running 100% and then after a while only one core is 100% while the others all go down to around 10%

Comment: Post the [actual code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise, nobody is able to help you.